# Need help in understanding how to solve for foot of perpendicular involving complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

As the title suggests, I would like to solve for the foot of perpendicular involving complex numbers. In fact, I have already worked out the solutions, but I need help in understanding certain parts of my workings.

Suppose that the circumcircle of triangle A$BC$ is the unit circle. We use the complex numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ to represent the vertices as mentioned. Also, let W be an arbitrary point on the circle. Clearly, $|a|=|b|=|c|=|w|=1.$

I would like the find the foot of perpendicular, denoted by $P$ from $W$ to the line $AB$. This is how I've done it:

The equation of a line passing through arbitrary points $s_1$ and $s_2$ in complex form is well known and is given by: $$z+s_1s_2\bar{z}=s_1+s_2.$$
In our question, since $p$ lies on the line $AB$, we have that $p$ must satisfy $$p+ab\bar{p}=a+b \text{ -------$(\star)$}$$ and $$p-ab\bar{p}=w-ab\bar{w}\text{ -------$(\star \star)$}$$

Solving both $(\star)$ and $(\star \star)$ yields $$p=\dfrac{a+b+w-ab\bar{w}}{2}.$$

I sought for some help to obtain $(\star \star)$ and I am unable to understand how it is obtained. Is it supposed to be the equation of perpendicular bisector of the line $AB$, passing through the points $W$ and $P$? I am mainly confused by the negative sign as it is not our usual definition of a line. Also, I have tried to expand $|z-z_1|=|z-z_2|$ (eqn of bisector) but it does not match up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Firstly $W$ can be ANY point in the complex plane, not necessarily a point on the unit circle (but you get the same formula).

The slickest way to compute the formula for $P$ is like this: Since $WP \perp AB$, the vectors $(W-P)$ and $(P-A)$ are perpendicular to each other, so the complex number $Z = \frac{W-P}{P-A}$ has real part equal to zero, i.e $Z = \bar{Z}$. You can derive it by letting $P = \mu A + (1-\mu)B$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ (this way is better to handle points in a line rather than the formula you mentioned) and computing $\mu$.

Comment: I believe you know where I'm going. Indeed, $W$ can be any point on the complex plane. Why is it that $Re(Z)=0$, where $Z=\frac{W-P}{P-A}$? Wouldn't showing $iWP=AP$ better? In any case, is it possible for you to help me work out more details?

Comment: $Re(Z) = 0$ because if for any two numbers $Z_1, Z_2$, if $Z_1O \perp OZ_2$ then $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ is purely imaginary. To see how this is related with the original question - parallel translate each vectors ($W-P$, $P-A$) such that one of the endpoints coincide with the origin. For the second question, "Wouldn't showing $iWP=AP$ better?" - well (I believe you're asking this for complex bashing Euclidean geometry problem for olympiads ?) you'll get the intuition which way to compute requires less fortitude after you bash loads of geo problems.